# Parse Arduino Uno data directly to IoT

Tags: azure, arduino, iot, arduino-uno, azure-iot-hub

I'm making a temperature, humidity and moisture sensor system where data should be sent over to Iot hub (Cloud) every second. I have used an Arduino and Ethernet shield.

I'm able to create sensor data every second. It sends this data to the IoT hub directly from Arduino without a Raspberry Pi or PC|VS Studio. I have already created a job stream on Azure as well. Is there any mechanism with which I could send this data to Azure IoT hub directly? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the libraries for IoT Hub here: 
[Azure IOT SDK for C](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c)

A Quick search on the Arduino site also contains lots of examples of devices connecting to the IoT hub. I imagine you can use both AMQP and also MQTT protocols for this directly from your Arduino. I'm using MQTT in my ESP8266's without VS involved, all written in the Arduino IDE.

Answer (score 1):

You can also find the Azure IoT Arduino libraries [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-arduino).

Note that required libs (AzureIoTHub, AzureIoTUtility, AzureIoTProtocol_HTTP and AzureIoTProtocol_MQTT) are all published in the Arduino IDE lib manager, so you can just install them from there (no need to clone the repos).

The docs and the samples are not quite up to date (which we'll fix real soon) but you can find an MQTT sample in the [MQTT lib repository](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-arduino-protocol-mqtt/tree/master/examples).